# How can I rephrase sentence to make it more concise?

Tags: grammar, sentence

**What I am trying to say:**

A farmer should provide essential food for his livestock. The failure of farmer to provide this essential food for the cattle will materially impact cattle's health. Farmer's boss is going to hold him responsible only if he does not provide the essential food that directly impacts the health of the cows and but will not hold him responsible for if essential food does not impact the health of cow (e.g. is only good for cow's fur/skin - aesthetic conditions.)

**my concise version**

The farmer's boss will hold the farmer responsible if farmer does not provide essential food that considerably impacts the health of a cow and does not lead to aesthetically unpleasant health.

**Question**

How do I frame what I am trying to say in one sentence which is better than my version above. I believe my version is not clear (esp. at the tail end of the sentence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be trying to convert legalese into "plain language".  There is excellent advice on how to do this well in two books by Rudolf Flesch: [The Art of Plain Talk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0020463804) and [The Art of Readable Writing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0020464703).

For this specific example, I would recommend something like this:

> Farmers will be held responsible for failing to feed their cows properly, if this has a serious effect on the cows' health.  If it only has a cosmetic effect, they will not be held responsible.

The key change is to replace the elliptical phrase "provide essential food" with the direct verb "feed".  All else flows from that decision.

Answer (score 1):

The boss will hold the farmer responsible for providing food essential to the the cattle's health, not to its aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

A farmer is responsible for providing cows with proper food, if it has an impact not only on aspect, but health too.

When impacting on cow's health, not merely aspect, a farmer is responsible for providing good food.

Answer (score 0):

The farmer will be held responsible by his boss for ensuring he feeds his livestock with essential foods to keep health intact. He however is exempt from feeding practices that ensure the superficial health of the livestock